# Does Leviticus 18:19 say women should be put apart during the menstrual cycle for health reasons or for defilement?

Tags: leviticus, context, gender, sexuality

Deliberate preaching of the "whole counsel of God" will naturally encourage pastoral caregivers to continue the important conversation in Leviticus 18 as it carefully illustrates the pitfalls and the trappings, as well as the beauty and the blessing associated with sexuality.

But coming to verse 18, one cannot help but wonder if God's Word is too straitlaced about sexuality.

> “You shall not approach a woman to uncover her nakedness while she is
>   in her menstrual uncleanness. (ESV)

Diverse cultural voices tell us that sex is a drive similar to hunger and might even allow the act of sex in ways that contradict popular view of the Scriptures. Other voices simply discard the prohibition in verse 19 as a way society views menstruation, while others would yet not allow women to come close to men or enter the church during the menstrual cycle.

Does Leviticus 18:19 uphold the views that women should not be allowed to come close to men or enter the church during menstrual flow? Does it say women should be put apart during menses for health reasons or for defilement?

Comment: Could you be specific on what you mean by the phrase "the modern secretive oppressiveness of women?"

Comment: I have edited "the modern secretive oppressiveness of women" out of the question.

Answer (score 3):

The word used to denote intercourse in the OT is משגל, "mishgal".  However, the Hebrew most often uses several euphemisms for sex.  "approach to uncover nakedness" is one such.  "Adam knew his wife" (Gen 4:1) is another.

Therefore, Lev 18:19 is simply saying that sex should be avoided during menses. In ancient Israel there were several good reasons for this:

- blood is a potent vector of disease that modern medicine has discovered.  Read the history of what happened when surgeons began washing between operations - survival rates went from very low to very high immediately.  This is still mandatory surgical practice despite modern antibiotics.
- It teaches married couples that a little self control is a good thing.  Many poor marriages could be made much better with some self control rather than just giving vent to feelings (and hormones) whenever the mood strikes one of the partners - often the wife is disinclined during menses.  Sexual intimacy should be mutually agreed (1 Cor 7:1-5) rather than demanded by one partner.

Whatever people say about the Bible, it is NOT (repeat NOT) secretive nor ashamed nor prudish about sexual intimacy - read the Song of Songs - if this were made into a movie today it would be XXX rated - it is one of the greatest celebrations of sexual intimacy ever written and achieved with a beauty of language that is unsurpassed.

The Bible records some appalling sins against women (and men) but that is obviously not what the Bible teaches.  The Bible ideal for women can be seen from the following:

- The ancient Israelite patriarchal society did not prevent women from inheriting property.  Num 27:1-11, 36:1-12, Josh 17:3-6.
- Women could be significant leaders, eg., Deborah.  Judges 4.
- Women could be prophets of God; eg, Miriam (Micah 6:4, Ex 15:20, 21), Deborah (Judges 4:4), Huldah (2 Kings 22:14-20), Isaiah’s wife (Isa 8:3), Anna (Luke 2:36), The four daughters of Phillip (Acts 21:8, 9), etc.
- Women could buy and sell property.  Prov 31:16.
- Women could earn independent income and use it at their discretion.  Prov 31:11, 16, 18, 20, Acts 16:12-15, 40.
- Men were required to treat women and wives with great respect – in fact, they were to treat wives as Jesus would love them – enough to give His life for them.  Eph 5:25.
- A man could not divorce his wife on whim and marry another without being guilty of adultery.  Matt 19:9 (very different from Roman law), Gen 2:24.
- A man could not deprive his wife of marital privileges.  1 Cor 7:2-4.  (The same was equally required of women.)
- Paul had female co-workers in Euodia and Syntyche (Phil 4:2, 3) as well as Junia the apostle (Rom 16:7).  Nympha appears to be the leader of the church that met in her house at Laodicea (Col 4:15).  John also addressed an epistle to a female church leader (2 John 1).
- Women are specifically mentioned as being deacons (using the masculine noun for the female in the Greek!!).  Rom 16:1, 2, 1 Tim 3:11.
- The New Testament church was specifically instructed to care for elderly women who could not support themselves .  1 Tim 5:9-13.
- Women were allowed to teach men.  The female leader, Pricilla taught the Apostle Apollos “more adequately”, Acts 18:26.  It is significant that Pricilla is listed before her husband, Aquila, in this passage.  King Lemuel was taught by his mother, Prov 31:1-9.
- Gal 3:28 declares that all gender distinctions are out of place for the Christian congregation

In modern society, again, women are often oppressed, and sometimes by Bible wielding elders and church leaders; but that is NOT what the Bible teaches as shown above.

Comment: Thank you.  Too many times ppl focus on the evil that was done against women in the OT and somehow come away the idea that b/c the Holy Spirit recorded those events, then God must have approved or condoned that behavior.  He values both his sons and daughters, and hates the wicked sinful actions of us all.

Comment: I appreciate this post because most Christian traditions still believe that approaching a woman during menses is a grave sin. They would not even allow them come into the church nor go near the altar as they claim such acts amount to defilement.

Comment: Most of the laws in Lev 18 are a prohibitions against incest of various kinds, plus bestiality, adultery and child abuse.  Lawful sex in the Torah was with the lawful wife and husband.  Very simple!

Comment: Good answer +1.

Comment: 'Ye shall not' is not advice. It is a prohibition.

Comment: @Nigel J: Glad to see your post. "That women should be put apart during menses" should not be discarded as ancient or for mere health reasons. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It shows how Jehovah wanted men to respect women during this time of thier cycles of life for the following reason:-

> Jacob B. Glenn in his book The Bible and Modern Medicine: “The female genital tract, especially during periods of lowered resistance (menstruation), is particularly vulnerable to irritation and stimulation; hence, the strict law among Jewish people forbidding cohabitation during this period.”
>
> NWT Proverbs 31:10 "Who can find a capable wife? Her value is far more than that of corals."